# firebase query method where clause with AND

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do a `WHERE foo = bar AND something = also_something` in firebase

```
export const getAllRoomsWhichHaveUnreadMessages = (currentUserId) => {

    return query(
        roomsRef,
        where(USERS_PATH, 'array-contains', currentUserId), 
        where('unreadCount', '>', 0)
    )
}
```

How do I chain `WHERE`s and also how  do I retrieve them? My above code works but it only outputs a query, how do I `run` the query ?

Comment: You may have a look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `getDocs` method to get a snapshot of the query.

You can then map the docs of that snapshot.

```js
import { query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
    export const getAllRoomsWhichHaveUnreadMessages = async (currentUserId) => {

    const q = query(
        roomsRef,
        where(USERS_PATH, "array-contains", currentUserId), 
        where('unreadCount', '>', 0)
    )

    const querySnap = await getDocs(q);
    return querySnap.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
    }
```